# regular expression to match Google Content Categories

Tags: regex, expression

I’m looking to write a regular expression that captures path groups in [Google content categories](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/categories) for example given:

`/Arts & Entertainment/Comics & Animation/`

It constructs a set of group matches such as:
Full match 0-40: `/Arts & Entertainment/Comics & Animation`
Group 1. 0-40: `/Arts & Entertainment/Comics & Animation`
Group 2. 0-21: `/Arts & Entertainment`

I have tried using something like this: `((\/.*?[^\/]*)\/.*?[^\/]*)`
see this [in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SAk804/8) it performs the above grouping.

The trick is if another forward slash section is added to that same string it should refuse to match it completely, so:

`/Arts & Entertainment/Comics & Animation/Anime & Manga`

Should result in no match

Comment: ... but `/Arts & Entertainment/Comics & Animation/Anime & Manga` is a valid category, why wouldn't you want it to match? I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve exactly.

Comment: Doesn't [`^((\/[^\/]+)\/[^\/]+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/vuGGT9/1) work?

Comment: @GalAbra That will match `/foo/bar`, but will **not** match `/foo`, `/foo/`, or `/foo/bar/`.

Comment: This could use a more descriptive title

Comment: So should it only match strings in the format `/X/Y/` with `/X/Y` being the first group and `/X` being the second group? If so, you could use [`^((\/[^\/]+)(?:\/[^\/]+)?)\/?$`](https://regex101.com/r/KihIoa/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could prepend a negative lookahead:

`^(?!(\/[^\/]+){3,})((\/.*?[^\/]*)\/.*?[^\/]*)`

This checks to see that the string it is about to match does not contain three or more sets of your slash groups...

Comment: Thank you Bananaapple! Very elegant solution. This seems to work for me with all the cases I've tested.

Answer (score 0):

Add a guard at the beginning of the regular expression to test for the presence of three slashes or more, and fail if it is the case:

```
^(?![^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*$)((\/.*?[^\/]*)\/.*?[^\/]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may fit your needs.

`^(?:\/)([^\/]+)(?:\/)?([^\/]+)?(?:\/)?$`

- **/foo**

[image]

- **/foo/**

[image]

- **/foo/bar**

[image]

- **/foo/bar/**

[image]

- **/foo/bar/baz**

[image]

Given a match,

- Group 1 will always yield the trimmed first category.
- Group 2 will always yield the trimmed second category (if it exists).

Comment: If capturing leading forward slashes is desirable, use [`^(\/[^\/]+)(\/[^\/]+)?(?:\/)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/tYvKaT/1)

Answer (score 0):

Beside removing unnecessary patterns in your regex, you should use beginning and end of string anchors (caret `^` and `$` respectively):

```
^((\/[^\/]*)\/[^\/]*\/)$
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/xfJXF2/1)

Comment: `.*` patterns in the original regex are not just unnecessary, they are clearly wrong as a dot matches any character and cannot be relied upon when a delimited string is validated.